# "No subscription were found" in VS code while sign in using Azure account

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create an azure function in VS code. When I click on "Select Subscriptions...".I am getting the following error message 
**"No subscriptions were found. Set up your account at [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/."](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/.%22)**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRonj.png)

I have checked my subscription and I have upgraded to ***"Pay as you go subscription"***.

Things I tried for now:

- Signing-out and signing-in VS code
- Removing all the extensions and installing it again
- Signing-out Restarting and Signing-in  VS Code.

Please help me with this issue

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No. I am not using proxy. As soon as I click the link in error it opens Microsoft edge and asks me to upgrade.

Comment: @ANANTHABALAJI.D Can you post a screenshot of your VS Code window?

Comment: I have the same problem, looking forward to someone posting a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows the vscode created a temporary cache in **AppData** of user. Remove it and try reinstalling the extensions.

This solved my problem. Thank you for everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to sign out from Azure account in VSCode using command palette typing:"Azure: Sign Out".
After, Sign in again typing "Azure:Sign In".

It may sound silly but it worked for me.

Comment: Posting walkthrough using images and steps would be helpful here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What works for me:

- Open in VS Code View-> Command palette
- Type "Azure: Sign Out"
- Type "Azure: Sign In"

Now it worked!

Comment: This information appears to have been covered in another existing answer.