# VS Code does not find my Azure subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I have followed the instructions found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration but after I login VS Code cannot find my subscription. I do have a pay and go subscription active so why does this not work? I need to be able to create a python function in VS Code and need this to work to be able to move ahead....

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: No errors, but I discovered that I also had to be logged in Azure in the browser at the same time otherwise it does not find my subscription

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get my azure subscription in VS Code.

- Firstly, when I opened VS Code, I could not be able to see my subscription.
- Then I logged into my Azure Account in Azure Portal Website in my Browser, then I am able to see the Subscription as below in VS Code.

[image]

**References:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382060/azure-vs-code-39no-subscriptions-were-found39.html
- ["No subscription were found" in VS code while sign in using Azure account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222580/no-subscription-were-found-in-vs-code-while-sign-in-using-azure-account)

Comment: Yes I discovered that too, but this is not obvious because when you sign in a browser open and then you are prompted that the browser can be closed. But as stated above one need to be logged in to Azure in the browser otherwise it does not work