# VS Code Can't Azure Function Extension subscription error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I try to create a new python Azure Function using VS Code,
I can list of a resource groups in my subscriptions
(I'm a owner of the subscription)

[image: list of a resource groups]

But when I try to create a new function (python - 3.11 - consumption)
I got this error:
[image]

The number of subscription is OK

I tried to Azure log out and log in, even with machine code,
also I restarted whole computer.

I have 1.84.2 of VS Code it's last one and nothing can be updated

What I can do to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this error, In order to resolve this error. **Visit your Account settings** in VS CODE and specify your **Azure TenantID/SubscriptionID** in **settings.json** file. Reload your VS code and try to Create the Function App, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

My **settings.json** including ***tenantid/subscriptionid*** in the ***azure.resourceFilter*** :-

Make sure you edit your **settings.json** file to include ***azure.resourceFilter*** setting specifying your ***Azure Tenant and Subscription ID.*** I have two Azure accounts thus, I have specified two settings:-

**My settings.json:-**

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "azure.resourceFilter": [
        "xxxxxTenantIDxxx7cd011db47/xxxxSubscriptionID-xxx3f",
        "xxxxxTenantID7xxxx95/xxxxSubscriptionIDxxxe2b6e97cb2a7"
    ],
    "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
    "circleci.hostUrl": "",
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "file:///c%3A/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/atlassian.atlascode-3.0.7/resources/schemas/pipelines-schema.json": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
    },
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.avro": "default",
        "*.pkl": "default"
    },
    "durableFunctionsMonitor.showWhenDebugSessionStarts": true,
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
        


    ],
    "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [

    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "azure.resourceFilter": [
        "TenantID/SubscriptionID",
        "TenantID/SubscriptionID"
    ],
    "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
    "circleci.hostUrl": "",
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "file:///c%3A/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/atlassian.atlascode-3.0.7/resources/schemas/pipelines-schema.json": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
    },
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.avro": "default",
        "*.pkl": "default"
    },
    "durableFunctionsMonitor.showWhenDebugSessionStarts": true,
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
        


    ],
    "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [

    ]
}
```

Save the **settings.json file** and then **Reload your VS Code** and Try creating your Function again.

According to this [**SO Thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222580/no-subscription-were-found-in-vs-code-while-sign-in-using-azure-account) by ANANTHA BALAJI .D try to remove the above user cached in App data folder that you will find here- **`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`** and try installing the Azure Functions Extension again.

Try to Uninstall and Re-Install the Azure Functions extension again and reload your vs code:-

[image]

Try to sign into your ***Azure account via View > Command Pallette > Azure:Sign in > You will be prompted to sign into your account, Sign into your Azure account > After successful Sign in > Go to your Azure Extension and try creating the Function App again***:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

And create your Function:-

[image]

***Click on your Signed in account at the bottom and then select your subscription:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Validate your Azure account from this section:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add record of tenant/subscription, also deleted whole User folder from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User.
But still got the same error :-(

Comment: @LevGelman Okay, Try to visit your Azure Account settings > Show settings > In workspace clear all Filter and then search this > Azure:tenant > And add your Tenant ID in the Azure Tenant Id and then sign in again, Refer here- https://i.imgur.com/svyZKKh.png Then try creating a Function app again. Also, In your workspace edit settings.json same as you did in user by adding tenantId/subscriptionId- https://i.imgur.com/kDS6gcW.png https://i.imgur.com/tctOS2T.png

Comment: @LevGelman Another command you can use is Azure: Select Subscriptions and select your Azure subscriptions in  View >command pallete. Or in your Account user and workspace settings add the Subscription here- https://i.imgur.com/96PvS53.png

Comment: Refer this MS Q & A answer for the same - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382060/azure-vs-code-no-subscriptions-were-found

Comment: After a long challenge, I just deleted C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Code folder, and configured whole VS Code from scratch, and it worked. Thank you all!